# Type or interface for location.state in react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

In one component, there is a `<Link>` (from react-router-dom) passing an object in the state property.

Another component called `ReceiverComponent` is receiving that object correctly. However, the code belows complains with the message:

> Type 'PoorMansUnknown' is not assignable to type 'locationStateProps'.
>   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'locationStateProps'.ts(2322)

```
type locationStateProps = {
  name: string;
}

function ReceiverComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const myState: locationStateProps = location.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {myState.name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to provide a type for the state some way without this error. How to proceed?

Comment: `state` can be undefined, hence the error. If you're absolutely sure it will always have a value you can use non-null assertion operator: `const myState: locationStateProps = location.state!;`

Comment: I did not know about the non-null assertion operator. Thanks.

Comment: Consider typing variable as  `const myState: locationStateProps | undefined = ...` and then `{myState?.name}` or something like this in case state can be undefined

Comment: Ok that is helpful. So far I have been developing with jsx and recently changed to typescript and getting used to it. All the information is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/41674) open on Github about this issue.

I implemented this solution mentioned on the thread and it worked.

```
interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<
  { myParamProp?: string }, // props.match.params.myParamProp
  any, // history
  { myStateProp?: string }, // props.location.state.myStateProp
> {
  myNormalProp: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also build your own state interface and cast it to it:

```
interface CustomState {
  ...
}

const location = useLocation()
const state = location.state as CustomState
```

Answer (score 3):

For others who may end up here… I'm using React Router v6, which, as far as I can tell, no longer exports `RouteComponentProps` (I installed @types/react-router and @types/react-router-dom — I see the type definition in the DefinitelyTyped files, but there is no export from `react-router-dom`).

So, the way `Location` is typed, I found myself unable to extend it in a way that would placate Typescript. However...

I wouldn't recommend `as` casting, because it reduces the efficacy of TypeScript. Good news! You can use `is` instead of `as` to prove to TypeScript that a given element is indeed what you say it is. E.g.:

```
type LocationStateProps = {
  name: string;
}

function ReceiverComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const myState = location.state;

  // note that you are defining the return type of this function using `is`
  const hasNameProps = (state: object | null | LocationStateProps): state is LocationStateProps => {
    // you use `as` here, but only so typescript doesn't yell at you while you access the property
    // specifically to test if it is there
    return (state as LocationStateProps).name !== undefined;
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {/**
       * Now you can check to see if the prop exists. If it does, us it confidently, and TypeScript won't
       * complain! But you're able to provide a fallback in case the value is, for some reason, not there.
       * If you as-cast, you lose that opportunity. It's a little verbose, but it preserves the benefit of
       * TypeScript... Type safety!
       */}
      {hasNameProps(myState) ? myState.name : "No Name"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
   interface locationStateProps {
  from: { isEditing: string }
}
const NewPublication: React.FC<NewPublicationProps> = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  let location = useLocation();
  const myState: locationStateProps = location.state as locationStateProps;
```

Comment: write perfect code format adds a close curly bracket.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).